# Is there a way to trigger an external event or app when Google Maps says "You have arrived"?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way to hook the "You have arrived" event in the Google Maps android app?

The Maps API can do this, but only if I recreate a lot of the functionality of the Android app, which is a lot of wheel to re-invent just to catch a single event.

Has anybody done anything similar.

The end result is that I want to toss a record into a database and start customer billing when arriving at the customer's location.

Comment: Why don't you just set a geofence around the place you want to go instead, and wait for an alert that you entered the geofence?  Leave Maps out of it entirely?

Comment: I could, but this seems like it should be such low hanging fruit. The app knows "I have arrived" and announces. I just can't figure out how to hook it's event.

Comment: The app doesn't announce events to other apps.  Does your app announce every click to every other app?  In this case that would even be a privacy breech-  it would be exposing location data to apps without that permission

Comment: @GabeSechan  Not "every click", but a lot of apps do expose at least some events.

Comment: No, very very few apps do that.  Almost none.  And all of them are very special purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there actually is an external API for "You have arrived" and a number of other map events.

However it's only available to "select customers" with a note to "contact sales", which seems to put it out of reach for individuals.